# "Select CD-ROM Boot Type:" error during Windows install

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

Which version of bootcamp 4.x do I need to install Windows 7 (64 bit) on an iMac7,1 with Yosemite?

Specs: 64 bit Core 2 Duo, 4GB, 16GB Flash, optical drive, Windows 7 install DVD

Everything goes fine until during the install process Mac reboots to install windows then:

1
2
Select CD Rom boot type:

I can't enter anything because keyboard and mouse are unresponsive and I assume the correct drivers were not loaded.

iMac is mid 2007 24" 64 bit (says profiler/other internal monitors).  Have downloaded various boot camp versions, followed documented instructions, stood on my head and spit nickels, and still get same error (Select CD Boot ROM type).  Made ISO file with Mac Disk Utility (create and change .cdr to .iso)  Didn't work either.

After further review, seems that I misread Apple support table which show this model uses Boot Camp 4 for 32-bit Windows 7.  Genius - bought install DVD for 64-bit :-o  So I guess that's why it won't install.

Going to try suggested method of creating ISO from W7 store-bought DVD on Windows machine just for giggles and see what happens.  Then probably go buy the correct DVD for 32-bit  :-(  Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: @DavidAnderson reopened. I still think the question could need some improvements though, so if you can help out the OP with the text here it would be great.

Comment: I first tried (this morning) using the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool, to burn the DVD. It made no difference. Besides the tool was difficult to install on my Windows 8.1 machine. You can not install from a flash drive. Your firmware does not support this. I did run Window 7 (64 bit) years ago on my iMac7,1 so I know it works.

Comment: If you choose to install a 64 bit version of Windows 7, 8 or 8.1, you will encounter problems installing the drivers. A fix for this can be found at [Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-or-8).

Answer (score 3):

The problem you encountered occurred before the Boot Camp drivers are installed. So, the drivers are not the problem. The correct drivers for Macs can be found at [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/100503). In your case, the drivers can be downloaded from [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630). Also, the drivers can be downloaded using the Boot Camp Assistant. By the way, I used the same drivers to do a clean install Windows 8 (64 bit) on my iMac7,1 (20-inch, Mid 2007).

Your actual problem is with the DVD itself. As you might guess, it came with two ways to boot. You need to remove one of them. You are using a Windows 7 DVD. I was having the same problem with a Windows 8.1 (64 bit) DVD. The procedure to repair should be the same.

I used a windows 8.1 machine and a copy of the program `oscdimg.exe` from Microsoft. The procedure should work just as well using a Windows 7 or 10 machine.

To begin, you will need to copy `oscdimg.exe` to your desktop. There are many web sites where a copy of this file can be found. I used `oscdimg.exe` Version 2.55 (x86). If you want to be sure you are using the same one I used, follow the steps below.

1. Go to the web site [The Windows® Automated Installation Kit (AIK)
   for Windows® 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753) and download the iso. This iso file is 1.7 GB in
   length.
2. Open the file `Neutral.cab`. If you are using a Windows 7 machine, you
   will need to burn the iso on to a DVD. The instructions can be found
   [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485). Open the new DVD to find the `Neutral.cab` file. It is
   faster to copy the `Neutral.cab` file to the desktop before opening
   it. If you are using a Windows 8.1 or 10 machine, right click on the iso
   icon and select Mount. `Neutral.cab` will be one of the files in the
   opened folder. (Note: Opening the file can take a while.)

   One way to avoid burning a DVD would be to copy (or download) the iso file to a machine running OS X. The iso file can then be mounted by double clicking on its icon. `Neutral.cab` will be one of the files in the opened folder. You will need to copy `Neutral.cab` back to a Window machine. I tested this using OS X 10.6.8. I assume this procedure would work using any newer version of OS X.

   Another way to avoid burning a DVD would be to copy (or download) the iso file to the `~/Downloads` folder of a machine running Kubuntu (or perhaps some other Linux). The following commands can be used to extract the `Neutral.cab` to the `~/Downloads` folder. You will need to copy `Neutral.cab` back to a Window machine. I tested this using Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   mkdir windowsiso
   sudo mount -o loop,ro KB#AIK_EN.iso windowsiso
   cp windowsiso/Neutral.cab .
   sudo umount windowsiso
   rmdir windowsiso
   ```
3. Using a Windows 7, 8.1, or 10 machine, extract `oscdimg.exe` from the
   `Neutral.cab` cabinet file. The x86 (32 bit) version is named
   `F1_oscdimg`. The x64 (64 bit) version is named `F3_oscdimg`. Right
   click on the file of your choice and select Extract. Place the
   extracted file on your desktop. Rename the extracted file to
   `oscdimg.exe`. (I did verify the correctness of this procedure by
   installing the entire package and binary file comparing the
   installed x86 and x64 `oscdimg` files with `F1_oscdimg` and `F3_oscdimg`,
   respectively.)

Next, make a new Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 installation DVD, follow these steps. The procedure was tested using a Windows 8.1 installation DVD.

1. Make sure a copy of `oscdimg.exe` is on your desktop.
2. Place the original Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 installation DVD in the optical drive. If using a Windows 8.1 or 10 machine, then a Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 installation iso file  could be mounted instead.
3. If you are using a Windows 7 machine, open a Command Prompt window
   by clicking the Start button [image: Start button], clicking All
   Programs, clicking Accessories, and then clicking Command Prompt. On
   a Windows 8.1 machine, look for the Command Prompt icon on the Apps
   page.  On a Windows 10 machine, look for Command Prompt under Windows System on the Start menu.
4. Change your working directory to the desktop by entering the
   following command in the Command Prompt Window.

   ```
   cd  %homepath%\desktop
   ```
5. Assuming D: is your DVD drive or drive letter assign to the mounted Windows installation iso file, enter the following command. Be sure
   to replace the letter before each : with the drive letter of your
   DVD drive or mounted file. The file `new.iso` will be created on your desktop.

   ```
   oscdimg  -n  -m  -bD:\boot\etfsboot.com  D:\  new.iso
   ```

   > Note: For more information, see the Microsoft website [Oscdimg Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options).

   Using this command, on a Windows 8.1 (64 bit) DVD, produced the following output.

   ```
   C:\Users\David\Desktop>oscdimg -n -m -bD:\boot\etfsboot.com D:\ new.iso

   OSCDIMG 2.55 CD-ROM and DVD-ROM Premastering Utility
   Copyright (C) Microsoft, 1993-2007. All rights reserved.
   Licensed only for producing Microsoft authorized content.


   Scanning source tree (2000 files in 803 directories)
   Scanning source tree complete (2094 files in 867 directories)

   Computing directory information complete

   Image file is 3277371392 bytes

   Writing 2094 files in 867 directories to new.iso

   100% complete

   Final image file is 3277371392 bytes

   WARNING: This image contains filenames and/or directory names that are
    NOT COMPATIBLE with Windows NT 3.51. If compatibility with
    Windows NT 3.51 is required, use the -nt switch rather than
    the -n switch.


   Done.

   C:\Users\David\Desktop>
   ```
6. Burn `new.iso` on to a DVD. The instructions for a Window 7 machine
   can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485). The same instructions can be used for a
   Windows 8.1 machine. For a Windows 10 machine, find the `new.iso` file in the File Explorer, then right click on the `new.iso` file and select `Burn disc image`.

   > Note: The current 32 bit Windows 10 (20H2) release can be burned to a DVD or a rewritable (RW) DVD. However do to the larger size, the current 64 bit Windows 10 (20H2) release can only be burned to a dual layer (DL) DVD.

   You can also transfer the `new.iso` file to a OS X machine and burn to a DVD using the Disk Utility.
7. Finally, install Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 using the new DVD.

Comment: Appreciate your excellent assistance.  Win7 installed, however  Boot camp drivers (both 4.0.4033 and 4.0.255) will not install. (64 bit not supported)  If you would kindly post your afore mentioned solution it would be most helpful.  Thanks

Comment: @dazednconfused: The answer to your (64 bit not supported) question has been posted [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-or-8). Let me know, if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable assistance.  Win7 up and running on iMac7,1 with BootCamp4033 drivers.  You have provided me with better assistance than the Apple or Microsoft support sites.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue on my iMac 2007 model with Yosemite installed. I used the 64 bit disk and got the select CD-ROM boot type message and my keyboard/mouse was non responsive. I powered off my Mac and then ejected the disk and put in the 32 bit Windows install disk instead and the installation continued like nothing was ever wrong. So the issue in my case was that the installation for Boot Camp needed the 32 bit version of Windows 7 not 64 bit. I hope this helps someone else also. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. After selecting CD as boot device, immediately press "1" on your keyboard and keep it pressed.
2. When you see a black flash, press enter (without releasing "1"). This happens twice, press enter both times.
3. Keep "1" pressed until you see the disc has actually began booting.

Source: https://medium.com/@mark.stanislav/fixing-select-cd-rom-boot-type-when-booting-windows-or-linux-on-a-mac-76bde5d6a593#.dl3olstb9

Comment: It took me a few tries but it eventually worked. It was important to time the Enter keys just right on the first black screen and then the second one for me had a  single flashing cursor. If you see the "Select CD-ROM Boot Type" screen  again then it didn't work. Then, once I saw the Windows logo I had to press some other key before it would continue loading.

Comment: I've been trying this for nearly an hour on a 2007 MacBook, with no success. I've read the instructions in a few places but they don't seem to work. I've even resorted to spamming enter while holding down 1 and button mashing. The issue is that there's only one black screen before the prompt shows up and disables keyboard input which is really frustrating. The 1 shows up but eventually nothing else happens

Comment: @RonnieJ has the answer for that below: you need a 32bit version of Windows. I had same issue when using 64-bit Windows install disk with my 2007 MacBook. Switching to 32-bit it just worked.