# Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7, 8 or 10

Tags: bootcamp, windows

My computer is a iMac (20-inch, Mid 2007). The model identifier is iMac7,1. The processor name is Intel Core 2 Duo, which means I have a 64 bit machine. The Apple web site [Boot Camp: System requirements for Microsoft Windows operating systems](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048) shows the only downloadable Boot Camp support software for my Mac is for the 32 bit version of Windows 7. I can successfully install the 64 bit DVD installation versions of Windows 7 and 8 on my machine. The problem I am having is with the [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630). When I follow the instructions and double click on setup.exe, I get the following popup.

[image: Installation Error]

How do I successfully install this support software and avoid this popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This has been tested for Windows 7, 8 and 10.

These are the instructions for a Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 (64 bit) installation. Here, I assume the Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 has been copied to a flash drive. The instructions were adapted from the originals given [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630).

1. Determine the drive letter of your flash drive, by inserting the
   drive in a USB port on the Mac. Below is an example of the expected
   popup. This image shows F: as the drive letter. Your drive letter my
   be different. You can close this popup.

   [image: Flash Drive Popup]
2. Open a Administrator Command Prompt window by left clicking the
   Start [image: start button] button, left clicking All Programs, left
   clicking Accessories, ***right*** clicking Command Prompt, and then
   left clicking Run as Administrator. When prompted to allow changes,
   click on Yes. The window should appear as shown below.

   [image: Administrator Command Prompt]
3. Assuming F: is your flash drive, change your working directory by
   entering the following command in the Administrator Command Prompt
   window. Be sure to replace the letter before the : with the drive
   letter of your flash drive.

   ```
   cd  /d  F:\Drivers\Apple
   ```
4. In the Administrator Command Prompt window, enter the following
   command to start installing the Boot Camp Support Software.

   ```
   BootCamp64.msi
   ```
5. Follow the onscreen instructions.
6. Installation can take a few minutes. Don't interrupt the
   installation process. When installation is complete, click Finish in
   the dialog that appears.
7. A system restart dialog box appears. Click Yes to complete the
   installation.

Comment: I also successfully tested this solution using a Windows 8 (64 bit) installation DVD. Note: Step 2 will be sightly different. After installing, I went to the Windows store and downloaded the free upgrade to Windows 8.1. If you have any questions, please post them.