# Which version of Windows will run on an iMac 24" early 2009 model?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows

I have an iMac 24", early 2009 model with 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 4 GB RAM running OS X Yosemite.  I need to setup my Boot Camp and have done a lot of research, learned a lot but still unsure on a couple of points.

Based on my iMac's hardware, Microsoft tech support recommended the 64 bit version of Windows 8.1 Pro.  With Boot Camp Assistant 5.1.3, I tried and kept getting an error message that my Boot Camp only support Windows 7.

I did see that on the Apple's Boot Camp Support site, my iMac model can only run 32 bit Windows 7.  However, on the EveryMac.com, it stated that some users reported success in running the 64 bit version with the correct drivers.

So here's my questions:
1.  Which drivers are they talking about?
2. Is my version (5.1.3) of Boot Camp Assistant the wrong one to use and that's why it failed to install the Windows 8.1 64 bit version?

Ultimately, I like to know which version of Windows (7 or 8, 32 or 64 bit) can I successful install using which version of Boot Camp Assistant?

I'd appreciate any suggestions or advices.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install Windows 8.1 Pro on my early 2009 24 inch iMac yesterday. Just a disclaimer: I DID NOT USE BOOT CAMP ASSISTANT TO INSTALL. For 2 days straight I troubleshooted boot camp assistant to try to get it to take my Windows 8.1 Pro to no avail. Out of frustration I googled 'how to run windows on a mac WITHOUT boot camp.' After finding a guide online, in a matter of about 30 minutes I had successfully installed Windows 8.1 Pro on my 2009 iMac. Here is the link to the guide....you can ask me any questions regarding this. 
See "[How To Install Windows 8.1 On Mac Without Boot Camp](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-8-1-on-mac-without-boot-camp/)".

Comment: Did you use a DVD or flash drive to install Windows? I don't think you can even create the USB flash drive using the Boot Camp Assistant for a 2009 iMac. I do agree your link does give a good example of the process. I thought, if the Boot Camp Assistant is not used, then you would have to bless the Windows partition before installing. Maybe you don't if using a USB flash drive. I done not have a new enough Mac to test this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple Web site "[System requirements to install Windows on your Mac via Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048)", your need "[Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US)". The web site also shows the only Windows operating system supported is Window 7 32-bit.

However, you may be able to run Windows 8.1 64-bit on your iMac. To find out, you will have to try using the instructions found at "[Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-or-8/174227#174227)". I have tested the instructions on windows 7 Pro and 8 Pro, but not yet on 8.1 Pro. Although, I am currently running Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit on via a Microsoft Store upgrade. Also, note my iMac is a 20-inch, Mid 2007.

As for your questions, let us go through them.

1. Which drivers are they talking about? Boot Camp Support Software
   4.0.4033
2. Is my version (5.1.3) of Boot Camp Assistant the wrong one to use
   and that's why it failed to install the Windows 8.1 64 bit version?
   No
3. Ultimately, I like to know which version of Windows (7 or 8, 32 or
   64 bit) can I successful install using which version of Boot Camp
   Assistant? My guess would be all of them, provided you do not use
   *any* version of the Boot Camp Assistant. Both my 2007 and 20011 iMacs can.

Ok, I probably should elaborate. If the Boot Camp Assistance wants to cooperate, go ahead and use it. If it does not, then either you can not physically do what you are attempting OR Apple does not want you to. If you do not use the Boot Camp Assistant, then here are the general steps for your computer.

1. Download the "Boot Camp Support Software
   4.0.4033" to a flash drive.
2. Create a MS-DOS (FAT) formated partition on your internal drive. The
   Disk Identifier for the partition must end in a number less than or
   equal to 4.
3. Bless the partition. This is done using the `bless` command in a
   Terminal window.
4. Insert the DVD and reboot the computer. Hold down the Option key
   during the reboot and select the DVD to boot from.
5. Install Windows.
6. Insert the flash drive and install the "Boot Camp Support Software".

Please, let me know how things work out.

Answer (score 0):

I used bootcamp.  But still did research to make sure i installed it well.  It was successful.  I'm now running windows7 64 bit on a 2010 iMac core duo 3ghz with 4gb ram.  Bootcamp will really be tricky.  You have to have experience in hard drive partitioning.  And yah do research.  Like I found out that once bootcamp is setup you have to press the OPTION/alt key when your iMac restarts so you could get into the DRIVE CHOICE MENU where you will see your windows drive. What bootcamp does is do the preliminary tasks indicated in the link shared by David above.