# Where do I get the correct Boot Camp Support Software for my machine?

Tags: bootcamp, snow-leopard, windows

I have an old Macbook running Snow Leopard. I have used Boot Camp (3.0) to install Windows 7. I understand that after installing Windows I need to install the Boot Camp Support Software.

Before installing Windows 7, Boot Camp Assistant gave me the option of downloading the support software. However, it turned out that this wasn't possible. I got the error message "Download could not continue. The Windows support software is not available online." So I installed Windows hoping I could get the support software from somewhere else.

I've downloaded several versions of the support software from:
https://support.apple.com/downloads/%255C%2522Boot%2520Camp%25203%255C%2522

…but none of these work when I run them in Windows. I get one of two messages: "This version of Boot Camp is not intended for this computer model" and "Boot Camp x64 is unsupported on this computer model".

I have also tried running the setup on the Snow Leopard install DVD. With this, I get the message: "Boot Camp x64 is unsupported on this computer model"

Windows works but I don't have audio so I want to install the correct drivers Can anyone point me to the correct version of the support software?

Specs of my installation:

- Macbook Core 2 Duo (4,1) Early 2009
- OS X Snow Leopard (fully updated)
- Bootcamp Assistant 3.0.4
- Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Although you do not explicitly say you are trying to install 64 bit Windows 7, can I assume this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the links given in [this tutorial](http://michael.anastasiou.me/boot-camp-x64-is-unsupported-on-this-computer-model/), you will find the drivers for your Mac can be downloaded from the Apple website [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US). If you are installing 64 bit Windows 7, 8 or 10, then you can follow the instructions given as the accepted answer to the question [Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-or-8).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following [this tutorial](http://michael.anastasiou.me/boot-camp-x64-is-unsupported-on-this-computer-model/) and running the support software supplied on the OS X installation disc using compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed list of BootCamp support software by year on the following Apple link. On ZIP format ready to deploy on Windows env.

https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/BootCamp