# Looking for Windows-10 drivers for MacBook Pro 5,5 (Mid 2009)?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, driver

I recently upgraded from Windows-7 to Windows-10 on my MacBook Pro 5,5 (Mid 2009) and none of the devices are working after the upgrade. The BootCamp drivers were working fine on Windows-7, but after the upgrade the devices listed below have stopped working -

1. Keyboard keys for Backlight, Screen Brightness and Volume control do not work
2. Trackpad pointer and hard click works but two finger right click does not work
3. Trackpad "Tap to click" does not work
4. No audio output
5. No USB audio connectivity but flash drives work

The "Device Manager" shows that all drivers are correctly installed with no conflicts, but they are all generic drivers. I have tried installing each driver individually from BootCamp driver list using the "Windows-7 Compatibility Mode" in Windows-10, and that did not help either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure Bootcamp on a mid-2009 MBP is fully compatible with Windows 10? In any case, I wish you best of the luck.

Comment: Win10 isn’t supported even on a PC of that age. There are no drivers. You’d be better off running it in a VM

Answer (score 0):

As per David Anderson's answer to [How to install OSX-Mavericks + Recovery + OSX-Catalina + Windows7/10 and make them all bootable on MacBook Pro 5,5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427657/how-to-install-osx-mavericks-recovery-osx-catalina-windows7-10-and-make-th), Windows-7/10 can be successfully setup using BootCamp Version 4.0 (Build 4033) on MacBook Pro (Mid 2009). The BootCamp Version 4.0.4033 can be downloaded from

"https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_IN"

Apple does not provide Windows-10 specific drivers for MacBook Pro 5,5 but the drivers provided along with BootCamp Version 4.0.4033 will work without a problem for Windows-10 Pro.

Posting an answer hoping it can help someone else.