# Which HDD controller drivers for win 10 Install on MacBookPro5,5

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp

I am trying to install Windows 10 on a MacbookPro5,5 for a friend, directly from a USB Flash drive. Setup Asks for a driver to properly detect the Hard Drive. What do you do in this case?

I extracted the drivers from the Bootcamp ESD, but I don't see anything related to HDD controller.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct boot camp ESD? Most likely a 2009 Mac would install Windows to BIOS boot. Do you intend to install a BIOS booting Windows 10?

Comment: Also Apple does not officially support Win10 on that model of Mac. Win 10 boot camp requires a MacBook Pro 2012 or later.

Comment: David, I have the correct bootcamp for MacBookPro5,5. And yes, am trying to install from boot/bios via USB bootable flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

The latest drives for your model Mac are contained in the [Boot Camp Support Software 40.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US) download. This is downloaded as a zip file and therefore does not contain a Bootcamp ESD. Windows on your model Mac should be installed to BIOS boot. This will require the internal installation drive that is MBR or hybrid partitioned. Since Boot Camp Support Software does not contain a `$WinPEDriver$` folder there are no drivers to load during the Windows installation. To install the Boot Camp software and any appropriate drivers after completing the Windows installation, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-8-or-10).

You have indicated that you can boot from a Windows installation USB flash drive. In order to use the Windows installer GUI to install a BIOS booting Windows 10, you have to be able to BIOS boot from the flash drive. This means you need to select the external drive icon labeled `Windows` from the Mac Startup Manager when booting from the Windows installer flash drive. If you are EFI booting from the Windows installer flash drive, then you can not use the GUI to install a BIOS booting Windows 10 to the internal drive. However you can use the CLI to install a BIOS booting Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you , but am not getting it completely . What is CLI installation ? I boot from the windows installation selecting it at boot time , and windows setup is run. You say there is. O driver available for the internal storage ? Then how would the CLI work?