# How to recover a shared (OS X-Win) FAT partition?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, data-recovery

How can I recover a FAT partition originally created under OS X and used mainly from Bootcamp Windows which now looks as follows:

- OS X diskutility shows it in grey, as unmounted partition `disk0s4` (despite a user-friendly name I given); attempt to mount it doesn't change anything. Capacity is shown correctly, but no Available/Used/Number of files is shown
- Windows 7: Computer > Manage > Disk Management shows the partition in the list (as RAW, Healthy, Primary), but again no capacity/used/free space is shown
- Windows Explorer reports:

  > "X:\ is not accessible. The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted".

Is there a "completely software" way to recover that partition (like re-creating MBR in some smarter way that I'm trying to do)--rather than to proceed to manually restoring file-by-file with some advanced dead-HDD recovery solutions?

---

As a background for the problem:

- I originally [created the following set of partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204636/54644) under OS MtLion X:

  1. bootable OS X MtLion
  2. bootable Yosemite
  3. Bootcamp (Windows 7)
  4. shared FAT32 data partition
- after(?) installing Windows on Bootcamp partition, I manually created MBR with the following subset of partitios to be visible under Windows: Bootcamp, Shared, MtLion. I used gdisk from gptfdisk (as detailed in [this post](http://cdacos.com/post/69010815918/boot-camp-and-multiple-partitions-on-macbook-air)).
- for several months I worked primarily under Windows, using Shared heavily
- recently I updated some piece of software under MtLion OS X (or Yosemite?) which(?) led to the above problem. I used to believe the update didn't deal with recovery partitions, but I may be wrong

Previously, every time OS X update created/updated recovery partition (and some of Windows partitions became inaccessible), simply re-creating MBR with the same original set of partitions helped every time. But it doesn't any more.

It's SSD installed to 13" MBP late 2010.

---

Per David Anderson's clarification, here are several logs:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *480.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD MtLion              100.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery SSD MtLion     650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         259.4 GB   disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS SSD Yosemite            29.2 GB    disk0s5
   6:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   7:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP SSD            90.0 GB    disk0s7
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HDD MtLion              100.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP HDD            65.0 GB    disk1s3
```

Here in `diskutil` output, `disk1` is HDD which currently serves as data-only; no problems with it--I just kept the output intact.

---

```
$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
Password:
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  195312496      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  195722136    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  196991672       1352         
  196993024  506595328      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  703588352       1832         
  703590184   57063864      5  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  760654048    1269536      6  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  761923584  175777792      7  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  937701376       1679         
  937703055         32         Sec GPT table
  937703087          1         Sec GPT header
```

---

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 58369/255/63 [937703088 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 -   25 127  14 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 196993024 -  506595328] HPFS/QNX/AUX
*3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 761923584 -  175777792] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 4: AF   25 127  15 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  195312496] HFS+
```

Comment: Post to your question the output from the commands `diskutil  list`, `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0`. None of the commands will change your computer. Your login password many be asked, this is normal.

Comment: If you had installed your Windows partitions before your OS X partitions, then these types of problems would not occur.

Comment: @DavidAnderson : I just added all the outputs, please let me know if I can provide any more info.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Sorry to bring up this, but do the output show some chances for recovery?

Comment: I do not see any error in the MBR partition table or GPT that would cause a FAT formatted partition to not mount. So, I do not know of a way to recover your files.

Comment: The partition doesn't look formatted even from OS X, although it aways was. That's the problem... @DavidAnderson