# Trying to install Windows 10 on early 2008 MBP without using the BootCamp Assistant

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, windows, macos

I have an early 2008 MBP, where I installed El Capitan. However I would like to split my HD and install Win10 as well. Since there is no direct support, it is quite difficult. 
I find this question ["How do I get Windows 10 installed on my macbook pro (late 2008)"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188578/how-do-i-get-windows-10-installed-on-my-macbook-pro-late-2008) here with a logical answer which was "How to install Windows without using the BootCamp Assistant." 
My issue is when I want to bless my HD in Terminal, I get the following error message "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc" and thus the rest of the instructions do not work.

Any suggestions, recommendations, idea how to solve it?

I already made a brand new OSX install, but the error is still the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but can you install Win 7 using the bootcamp that is designed for your system and then once installed *upgrade* to Win 10?

Note that the Windows 10 bootcamp drivers will not likely support your hardware but I have had some moderate success updating bootcamp drivers on Windows installations from within Windows by identifying any unsupported hardware by their hardware ID (in device manager) and then downloading the driver directly from the manufacturer.

Comment: Actually when I used Maverick I had Win 8.1 although it was said that it is also not supported. Certainly it could be a solution, but may be there is another solution to do a clean install

Comment: Upgrading from a fresh install of Windows is pretty safe as the only thing installed was put there by Microsoft. I do it all the time, works great. You may have to start with Win7, but that upgrades to Win10 just fine.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's what I did now. I just wanted to save some disk space by doing a clean install. Now I have 3GB trash that I do not know if it is a wise thing to delete it. (I already relocate the Bootcamp directory)