# Can I get drivers to run Win 7 64 bit on a MacBook 2.1 manually?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I have a working MacBook 2.1 mid 2007, i wish to run Win 7 64 bit. Is there a way to get the drivers i need manually? apparently running Win 7 64bit on this model is not fully supported.

Comment: Generally speaking (I've heard)  it's possible. But finding the drivers can be challenging as you need Windows drivers for Apple hardware. Often Apple uses "off the shelf" components. You'll need to find drivers for those components. Challenging.

Comment: In fact Windows installs the driver for the SigmaTel audio device that matches the one on the computer, but still i it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have never installed Windows on a MacBook. However, I have installed 32 bit Vista and Windows 7, 64 bit Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 on a 2007 iMac. I base my answer on the assumption your experiences would be the same.

For all 64 bit installs on Windows, I used the [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US). The Apple website [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016) indicates your Mac should use the same version of the Boot Camp Support Software. Instructions for installing this software are given as a answer to [Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-or-8/174227).

You should install Windows to BIOS boot. The main reason for this is that many of the drivers included in the Boot Camp Support Software are designed only for BIOS booting.

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), the Windows 7 installation media is suppose to include Service Pack 1 (SP1). Although, users have posted success installing without SP1. The Microsoft website [Installing Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2647609/installing-windows-7-on-your-mac-using-boot-camp) does not mention needing SP1.

I could not boot from the Windows 7 DVD because the DVD contained multiple ways to boot. If you have this problem, then see my answer to to [“Select CD-ROM Boot Type:” error during Windows install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172048/select-cd-rom-boot-type-error-during-windows-install/172128#172128)

USB flash drive based Windows installers would not work with my 2007 iMac. So, other than using the optical drive to install Windows, you could choose to use the procedure outlined in [Installing Windows 7 or 10 Pro 64 bit without DVD or Flash Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521)