# Installation of Win10 on MacBook4,1

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

I am trying to install Win10 on a MacBook 4,1. The Boot Camp Assistant doesn't download/find any drivers, so I had to choose the other option and download drivers by myself.

After partitioning and booting from the Win10 installation CD, the setup is missing some drivers. But unfortunately the previous downloaded drivers don't help here.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What drivers are you missing?  You can download bootcamp drivers using [brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier) on either macOS or Windows but *Windows Update* will pick up most things (on my MacBook Pro 2.1 it did anyway).

Comment: While it is possible to hack around and get Windows 10 to work on that Mac it is not *officially* supported by Apple. Meaning they do not have drivers for that Mac updated for Windows 10. So Boot Camp assistant won't find any compatible drivers, but you may be able to find drivers via Windows update or elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to install 32 bit Windows 7 with SP1 and then upgrade to 32 bit Windows 10. I say this because Apple officially supports 32 bit Windows 7 on your model Mac. Although Apple does not officially support Windows 10 for your model Mac, upgrading to 32 bit Windows 10 from 32 bit Windows 7 is should be supported by Microsoft. The Windows Support Software (the drivers) can be found by following the links on the Apple webpage [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016). I believe the correct link should lead you to [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US). You will probably need the optical drive to be working in order to install Windows 7 by using the Boot Camp Assistant application. If the optical drive is not available, then read the other pertinent options given below.

Window 7 can be purchase rather cheaply. For example, [this retailer](https://pcmarket-online.com/en/operating-systems/windows-7-professional-3264bit-download?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIodyEvfXc5gIVwsDACh2Phg9QEAQYASABEgJxnfD_BwE) offers Windows 7 Professional 32/64bit Download for 19.50 USD. You may still be able to upgrade to Windows 10 for free. See [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/266072/you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free-with-a-windows-7-8-or-8.1-key/) for details.

Your Mac has a 64 bit processor with 2 cores (Core 2 Duo). If you want 64 bit Windows, then there potential problems you may need to overcome. Some of these problems and possible solutions are given below.

- According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028142/windows-10-system-requirements), you will need at least 2 GB of memory.
- If your Windows 7 media does not include SP1, then you should get a newer ISO file from the Microsoft website [Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). The download is free, but you will need to enter your Windows 7 product activation key to enable the download.
- The current version of Windows 10 can found by clicking on [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Note: the link is dependent on the browser you are using. In other words, Safari will goto a different website than Microsoft Edge goes to. While the download is free, you may still need to buy a license key to continue using Windows 10.
- The Window Support Software may not work with 64 bit Windows. See the question [Using Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 to install 64 bit Windows 7, 8 or 10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-8-or-10) for installation instructions.
- Some 64 bit Windows installation configurations can both BIOS and UEFI boot. However, some early Intel Macs can not handle this type of configuration. If you have this problem, then you will need to remove the UEFI boot files. See the question [“Select CD-ROM Boot Type:” error during Windows install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172048/select-cd-rom-boot-type-error-during-windows-install) for instructions.
- The newer versions of macOS automatically install firmware updates. If you are running an older version of macOS (OS X) then you may need to manually install firmware updates. See [About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518) for more information.
- If you do not have a working optical drive, then you can try installing Widnows by using the rather complex method described in the question [No bootable device USB 2.0 MacBook Pro mid 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014).
- User have reported being able to install Windows by using a flash drive. In my opinion, your Mac is to old, but I will include the following link anyway: [Bootcamp - No ISO Option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now tried Win8.1 64bit instead of Win10 and the installation worked and the MacBook is running well. After that I searched for several drivers and right now there is only 1 driver missing for some USB hub, but USB is working?! I also tried to install several version of boot camp, but every single one doesn't starts with some error message, that this MacBook is not supported. :-/ I will try your boot camp version these days. Right now I am happy, that most of the things work! :-)

Comment: There is this concept of a "null" driver. If some hardware is redundant or not needed then Apple will place a "null" driver in the Windows Support Software. These these type of drivers prevent the Device Manager from displaying false errors. Unfortunately, when using the Windows Support Software on newer versions of Windows that Apple does not officially support for your Mac, the Device Manager will sometimes display false errors. So, if all the hardware is working correctly, I would not worry to much if errors appear in the Device Manager.

Comment: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-8-or-10) may answer how to install the Boot Camp Support Software (Windows Support Software).

Comment: Today I had more time to update the computer. Unfortunately the boot camp 4.0.4033 said, that this computer ist not supported. It is a Macbook4,1 with 64-bit Windows 8. :-/ The remaining problems are the different keyboard layout and that there is no right mouse button when using the touch pad. Everything else is good. Any ideas?

Comment: The [instructions for installing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/using-boot-camp-support-software-4-0-4033-to-install-64-bit-windows-7-8-or-10) the boot camp 4.0.4033 was tested using a iMac (20-inch, Mid 2007). It is possible that the instructions will not work for a  Macbook4,1. However, the instructions are for after you get the *"this computer is not supported message"*. Did you get the same message before and after using the instructions?

Comment: Shame on me, David! I was searching for the msi file in the wrong directory, didn't find it and run the normal exe file. :-) Now I read the instructions very carefully and will try it again as soon as windows finished the updates. Thank you very much and sorry for my stupidness. :-)

Comment: Yes, it worked! Boot camp installation worked that way, you described it. But with Version 5.x! :-) But the Touchpad is completely out of function and I don't know why. It worked a few days before. Any ideas? And thank you very much for the bootcamp tipps!

Comment: Sometimes Windows update will install hardware updates before the Windows Support Software is installed. This could effect the touchpad. Can you look at the history to see if any hardware updates were installed? The boot camp version has very little to do with the hardware drivers. In other words, a newer version of boot camp probably would not provide your mac with new or updated drivers. Does the touchpad appear in the Device Manager? If so, do any problems appear? Can you run Apple Software Update? My guess is probably not.